# Triggers and Animations

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, triggers

I have to following XAML

```
<Window.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.8" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
            </Trigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <BeginStoryboard.Storyboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0.8" />
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard.Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>


    </Style>
</Window.Style>
```

The MouseOver Trigger is not working when I have the EventTrigger present. Without the EventTrigger is working fine. How can I have both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The animation is keeping the opacity set to the final value, you need to give it a FillBehavior of stop.

```
<Window.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.8" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
                </Trigger>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <BeginStoryboard.Storyboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" FillBehavior="Stop">
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0.8" />
                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard.Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>


        </Style>
    </Window.Style>
```